# Parse text from a .txt file uploaded to memory in desired format C#

Tags: c#, parsing, parameters

fairly new to C# here...
...What I'm trying to do is parse a bunch of text to a webpage from a .txt file uploaded to memory.

Here's what the .txt file looks like

---

```
.RES B7=121
.RES C12=554
.RES VMAX=4.7μV
```

---

Again, it goes on like this for another 50 or so .RES'...
I've successfully got it to parse, but not in the desired format...
Here's how I want it to look on the webpage

---

```
B7.........121
C12.........554
VMAX.........4.7μV
```

> all inside of a hidden panel with id="outpt"... which is currently set to visible="false"
>
> ---

Here's the code i'm using in my C# Page

```
namespace Sdefault
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void btnUpld_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream theStream = file1.PostedFile.InputStream; //uploads .txt file     to memory for parse

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(theStream))
            {
                string tba;
                while ((tba = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    string[] tmpArray = tba.Split(Convert.ToChar("=")); //Splits ".RES B7=121" to "B7"... but for some reason, It prints it as
                                                                        //".RES B7.RES C12.RES VMAX"... I would ultimately desire it to be printed as shown above




                    Response.Write(tmpArray[0].ToString());
                    var.Text = tba;
                    outpt.Visible = true;
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Any pointers in which direction I should go with this?

Comment: It looked like you were having some trouble with the editor. I fixed it as best I could, but I may not have done it exactly as you intend. Feel free to roll it back if you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Open the file for reading
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader((Stream)file1.PostedFile.InputStream))
{
  // as long as we have content to read, continue reading
  while (reader.Peek() > 0)
  {
    // split the line by the equal sign. so, e.g. if:
    //   ReadLine() = .RES B7=121
    // then
    //   parts[0] = ".RES b7";
    //   parts[1] = "121";
    String[] parts = reader.ReadLine().split(new[]{ '=' });

    // Make the values a bit more bullet-proof (in cases where the line may
    // have not split correctly, or we won't have any content, we default
    // to a String.Empty)
    // We also Substring the left hand value to "skip past" the ".RES" portion.
    // Normally I would hard-code the 5 value, but I used ".RES ".Length to
    // outline what we're actually cutting out.
    String leftHand = parts.Length > 0 ? parts[0].Substring(".RES ".Length) : String.Empty;
    String rightHand = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : String.Empty;

    // output will now contain the line you're looking for. Use it as you wish
    String output = String.Format("<label>{0}</label><input type=\"text\" value=\"{1}\" />", leftHand, rightHand);
  }

  // Don't forget to close the stream when you're done.
  reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: you are using {0} twice in the string, it will only print lefthand.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on your formatting, but a simple Split and Format will do the trick.

On your split, you're getting everything before the `=` sign, whereas from your description, you want everything after it. e.g.

```
while(...)
{
   var line = String.Format("<label>{0}< />.........textbox>{0}< />",tba.Split('=')[1]);
   Response.Write(line);
}
```

Comment: When I say Lable>...< />, that means I want that piece to parse into a label... Also when I say textbox> < />

Answer (score 1):

if you take .RES B7=121 and split it on "=" then the index 0 would be .RES B7 and index one would be 121

if you want to further subdivide you wil have to split index 0 again using Chr(32) which would yield .RES as 0 and B7 as 1.

Can be done inline as suggested above with string formatting.

It looks as though you want someling like

```
String.Format("<label>{0}< />.........textbox>{1}< />",tba.Split('=')[0].Split(' ')[1],tba.Split('=')[1].);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. you have several issues here..

first, you are spliting using the =.. so you are splitting the string in two parts...
.RES B7=121 comes to:
tmpArray[0] = .RES B7
tmpArray[1] = 121

To avoid another split, the best you can do is to replace .RES with and empty string:

```
tmpArray[0] = tmpArray[0].replace(".RES","");
```

Then, you should be showing this somewhere on your page, so you should be writting:

```
Response.Write("<label>" + tmpArray[0].ToString() + "< />" + "<textbox>" + tmpArray[1].ToString() + "< />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to do 2 splits:

1st   `var tmpArr1 = tba.Split(' ')` will result in a string array `{".RES","B7=121"}`

2nd  `var tmpArr2 = tmpArr1[1].split('=')` will result in a string array `{"B7","121"}`

Then you can do:

```
   var line = String.Format("<label>{0}</label><textbox>{1}</textbox>",tmpArr2[0],tmpArr2[1]);
   Response.Write(line);
```